# Not able to select dropdown: Kendo UI + AngularJS, Selenium, Python

Tags: python, angularjs, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

(This website is developed using AngularJS and Kendo UI).

I wanted to select dropdown option `Application` but the issue is:

I am able to click on the drop-down menu but not able to click on a particular option.

```
<span title="" class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="True" tabindex="0" aria-owns="{{layout + buildingBlock.StepDataBinding[0].Id}}_listbox" aria-live="polite" aria-disabled="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="3978dd6e-e872-492c-a664-323f8a9b108e" style="">
  <span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default">
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-input ng-scope">    
      <!-- ngIf: vm.isIconVisible -->    
      <!-- ngIf: vm.isTextVisible -->
      <span ng-if="vm.isTextVisible" class="ng-binding ng-scope"></span>
      <!-- end ngIf: vm.isTextVisible -->
    </span>
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-select" aria-label="select">
    <span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down">
    </span>
   </span>
 </span>
<select kendo-drop-down-list="" k-options="vm.comboDataSource" k-data-source="vm.comboData" k-rebind="vm.comboData" k-template="vm.comboSelectEntityEnumTemplate" k-value-template="vm.comboSelectEntityEnumTemplate" ng-model-options="{getterSetter: true }" k-ng-model="vm.getStepModel()[0][buildingBlock.StepDataBinding[0].TargetField]" k-value-primitive="true" ng-class="vm.customComboBoxClass" name="ComboSelectEntityEnumBuildingBlock" id="ffc6424b-6954-4de3-b31e-5a95b085b771" ng-disabled="enableVisible({buildingBlockLogic:buildingBlock.StepLogics,'actionType':['IsReadOnly'],'defaultValue':vm.isReadOnly}) || (isWorkFlowItemReadOnly ||(vm.activityCheckOut &amp;&amp; vm.isOfflineDisabled))" entitytype="ITSystemApplication" data-role="dropdownlist" style="display: none;">
    <option value="7E32286E-91C9-48E5-8D9F-E80B46E061BA">Database</option>
    <option value="9EE9D591-BB83-45AF-82AD-571CB4AE1997">Application</option>
    <option value="A109EA93-7827-490A-AFF3-8DE08FCCDFCE">Operating System</option>
    <option value="DAB5D3A5-3DDF-4619-830E-B1045B396829">Network</option>
</select>
```

When I select any option manually it shows in above span element. Currently span text is blank.

I tried so many options but still not able to select.

Is there any solution?

I tried to click on `option` tag but it not works.